# Can a Windows service run as Administrator in Windows XP HOME?

Tags: windows-xp, services

Can a Windows service run under the Administrator in Windows XP HOME? I'm having some issues getting a service to run under the Administrator account on a client's WinXP Home PC, or is the Administrator account only meant to be used in Safe Mode in WinXP Home?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not run it under the system account?  On the local machine system has an even higher privilege level then administrator, and running services as system is usually very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to if you change your local security policy (gpedit.msc).  I would suggest against doing so, though.  As Zoredache said, I would look at either making a new local account or using the system account.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up telling the client, thanks!